# Pandas: How to replace fixed-length chunks of values with their function evaluation according to their index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm actively learning pandas, but still have much to learn. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

And I'm looking to replace each chunk of 60 wind direction values with the average wind direction for that period. I wrote a function to compute the average wind direction given the series/list:

```
def hourly_wind_average(WD):
    u_eastwest, u_northsouth = 0,0
    for i, direction in enumerate(WD):
        u_eastwest += np.sin(direction * np.pi/180)
        u_northsouth += np.cos(direction * np.pi/180)   
    EW_avg = -u_eastwest/len(WD) # averages in radians
    NS_avg = -u_northsouth/len(WD)
    avg_WD = np.arctan2(EW_avg, NS_avg) * 180/np.pi # average in degrees 
    if avg_WD > 180:
        avg_WD -= 180
    if avg_WD < 180:
        avg_WD += 180 
    return avg_WD
```

and I'm looking for a pandas-friendly way to replace values in my df. I figured out how to replace the entire column with its function evaluation (using df.apply) to change day-of-year formatting to a date:

```
df['DOY'] = df['DOY'].apply(doy_to_date, args=(year,))
```

but I'm not sure how this would extend to operating on specific chunks of the data. I could probably write loops to iterate through the column and replace values, but I imagine there's a better way.

Any advice or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find the rolling average of the Series. You can find documentation of how to do that here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: This looks very useful! My only questions are, 1. how would I apply my own wind averaging function, since the arithmetic average doesn't translate to wind directions (as 0=360 degrees), and 2. how would I apply that average to every value it's operated on, rather than just place it in one spot? I don't see anything in the documentation allowing for this.